# Passing Arguments from Javascript to Python Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I am trying to execute/call a python method(with one parameter) from inside Ajax Call. But I am having trouble passing the parameter from Ajax Call to Python Function. I am using Flask to connect the two.

Updated Code: 
Ajax Call(Javascript):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_result/" + input.value,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response) {
        output.value = response;
        alert(response);
    }
}).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
});
```

Python Code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/get_result/<url>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_result(url):
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

I have a backend Python Server running locally. But I am getting this as the error. (Running http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_result/google.com directly from browser shows me correct result, if it helps).

[Expected End Result: alertbox with message "Hello World"]

Error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2015 13:38:21] "GET /get_result/google.com HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 194, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 185, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 153, in write
    self.send_header(key, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 401, in send_header
    self.wfile.write("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Can you please suggest a work around for this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Revised Code: Ajax Call(Javascript):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_result/google.com",
    data: {field: input.value}, //passing some input here
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response) {
        output.value = response;
        alert(response);
    }
}).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
});
```

Python Code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/get_result/<url>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_result(url):
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Getting "127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2015 11:08:32] "GET /get_result HTTP/1.1" 404 -" as the error now after this change.

Comment: You need to pass parameter in your AJAX request as below:
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_result/myurldata",

Comment: Still Getting ""GET /get_result/google.com?field=google.com HTTP/1.1" 404 -". The end result required is an alert box with "hello world"

Comment: Can you please suggest the complete modified code ?

Comment: check the revised answer.

Comment: Had to Deleted my above comments as the code was not fully working. The Python Script is running at 127.0.0.1:5000/get_result/google.com. The HTML code for the above is running at localhost:63342/abc/index.html. But the end result alert box with 'hello world' is still not coming.

Comment: Updated the Original Question with the Error Trace.

Answer (score 1):

According to the flask documentation, functions decorated with `@app.route` don't take a `url` parameter. That explains the error you're getting.

It looks like you need to also do

```
from flask import request
```

so that you can access the request in your function. See here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object

Once you do that you can access the data/query params sent over by the ajax call according to the docs here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#incoming-request-data

Comment: tried this. but not sure about the implementation part for the same.

Comment: The route defines a variable named `url`.

Comment: @dim That was added in an edit made after my response was posted.

Comment: @dursk Any suggestion why the above code is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

The above error stack trace was due to Cross Region Call. Implementing CORS resolved the issue. 
Final Working Code:

Javascript Code:

```
function buttonClick() {
    makeCorsRequest('google.com');
}

// Create the XHR object.
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        // XDomainRequest for IE.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        // CORS not supported.
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}

// Make the actual CORS request.
function makeCorsRequest(url) {
    var tempURL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_result/" + url
    var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', tempURL);
    if (!xhr) {
        alert('CORS not supported');
        return;
    }

    // Response handlers.
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var text = xhr.responseText;
        alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + text);
    };

    xhr.onerror = function() {
        alert('Oops, there was an error making the request.');
    };

    xhr.send();
}
```

Python Code:

```
import flask
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/get_result/<url>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_result(url):
    return "Hello World"

@app.after_request
def add_cors(resp):
    """ Ensure all responses have the CORS headers. This ensures any failures are also accessible
        by the client. """
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = flask.request.headers.get('Origin', '*')
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, OPTIONS, GET'
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = flask.request.headers.get(
        'Access-Control-Request-Headers', 'Authorization')
    # set low for debugging
    if app.debug:
        resp.headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1'
    return resp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```